# Handling Potentially Dangerous Query String

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net-2.0, request.querystring

My project implements search (from default `HTML` page) and will redirect to the search page (`ASPX` page) and I'm using query string to pass the search value. I'm getting `potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value` server error when language is set to non-english (e.g. thai, cyrillic).

Is there any way to handle this from client side? Currently I can't find a way to handle this from the page itself (`Page_Load`, `Page_PreInit` isn't triggering).

Here's the code I used for redirecting:

```
function Search()  {
    var searchString = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
    location.href = "/Search.aspx?search=" + searchString;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried encrypting your querystring and decrypting on the redirected page?

Comment: Not yet, I posted my code to redirect in search page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `validateRequest="false"` to you .Net Page or Web.config file

OR

you can encode your url vars, adding `encodeURIComponent`:

```
function Search()  {
    var searchString = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
    location.href = "/Search.aspx?search=" + encodeURIComponent(searchString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is going to look roughly like code you may well have to disable this validation; but then you need to be ***really*** sure about your code handling, in particular avoiding XSS and SQL injection attacks. You should be able to set in the aspx `validateRequest=false` to disable on a per-page basis:

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" ...
```

or globally in the web.config if you need this everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that attribute and it's working. Is it possible to set this true from code-behind? Let's say I have validated request and it's valid, I wan't to set `ValidateRequest` to true, to avoid any attacks.